# Can one specify a Dart interface that may be implemented by classes with either sync or async methods?

Tags: dart

For a Dart component that uses remote services, I started by defining a Dart service interface as an abstract class (e.g. abstract class XService) and a mock class (class XServiceMock implements XService) with synchronous methods that implemented the service API which I used for testing the component. I am now starting to implement the real proxy (class XServiceImpl implements XService) and several of its methods use the ‘await/async’ language features. The ‘await’ requires that the containing method be annotated with async which requires a return type of Future<Something>  and puts it in conflict with the method signatures in XService. I want to be able to inject either the mock proxy or the real one without modifying the component source code. Can this be done and how?

```
XService (api)
XServiceMock implements XService (sync methods only)
XServiceImpl implements XService (mixture of async and sync methods)
```

Comment: http://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2015/02/01/what-color-is-your-function/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible. What you can do is specifying an async interface and returning a future from synchronous code.

```dart
return new Future.value(someReturnValue);
```

Comment: @ Gunter: I will try this. However, the implications are that the 'async' annotation requires a fundamental change in signature (the type of the returned value) and is not just an implementation detail as stated in Gilad Bracha's article "Dart Language Asynchrony Support: Phase 1".

Comment: I had troubles understanding these statements too at first. You cant compare a sync function to a funtion with the async modifier. Only if you have a function  which returns a future it doesn't matter if you add the async modifier to the function or not from the callers point of view. The async modifier still doesn't make async functions sychronous, it just allows using await in the body.

Comment: @wjohnson Yes, without threads, once you've gone asynchronous you can't go back. But this isn't because of the async/await syntax, the same problem is there if you use futures and streams too (or even if you use continuation passing style like in node). The async/await sugar really is just sugar for futures and streams, it doesn't change the signature. The only way to remove async calls from your code is via blocking calls and threads. The Dart team are currently experimenting with this in an experimental VM called fletch. https://github.com/dart-lang/fletch/wiki/Coroutines-and-Threads

Comment: @Greg: Helpful comment. It is sinking in that I’m trying to reach for coroutines or fork/join constructs inside an event-driven architecture. I found myself in agreement with many of the observations by the authors of the paper cited (Behren+) on the Fletch website you referenced. Comprehending flow of control in an application becomes much more difficult when callbacks are ricocheting around in requests/responses.

Comment: Cheers ;)  Did you get a chance to read the earlier link from one of the Dart developers. It talks specifically about the sync/async schism. http://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2015/02/01/what-color-is-your-function/  I'm looking forward to where things go with fletch. Up until now DartVM development has been based on old well tried ideas. Fletch is an interesting departure. Although the ideas are still old, these concurrency models are not a well trodden path. So it is much more interesting from a computer science perspective ;)